# Eliminar Recursivo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

si tengo un arbol de esta forma:

```
[
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "dad",
        idparent: null
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "child",
        idparent: 0
    },    
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "child 1",
        idparent: 0
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "child 1.1",
        idparent: 2
    },    
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "child 1.1.1",
        idparent: 3
    },    
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "child 2",
        idparent: 0
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: "child 2.1",
        idparent: 5
    },    
]
```

y quisiera eliminar algun registro(cualquiera), debo tomar en cuenta, que si el registro que estoy eliminando tiene hijos y aparte esos hijos tienen hijos,
entonces  tengo 2 funciones las cuales son:

```
   //Borro el padre
    const Delpadre = (id) => {
        Delhijos(id);
        const newData = categorias.filter( item => item.id !== id );         
        setData( newData ); 
    };

    //borro a los hijos del padre
    const Delhijos = (id) => {
        const hijos= Data.filter( item => item.idparent === id )

        for( const hijo of hijos){            
            const newData = Data.filter( item => item.id !== hijo.id );
            setData( newData ); 
            Delhijos(hijo.id); // para eliminar los hijos
        }       
    }
```

lo que esta sucediendo aqui es que esta eliminando solo el padre y no a los hijos, que debo mejorar para lograrlo?

Comment: me parece que tu pregunta esta mas basada mas en una opinión, lo cual no encaja en el formato de preguntas de StackOverflow, revisa [ask]. Podrías agregar lo que  has intentado y mostrar que tipo de error o problema se te presenta con lo que intentas.

Comment: Listo bro!!! aplique un update  gracias!

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/440264/54039), puede serte útil.

Comment: @Triby justo en el clavo!!! gracias mano!

Comment: Tu intención es eliminar solo a los hijos de un id? o eliminar al objeto padre con todos los hijos?

Comment: Saludos @Richard mi intencion era que si eliminaba un objeto y si el objeto que estoy eliminando tiene hijos, tambien eliminaría a los hijos del objetos.....  en la respuesta de Triby esta una forma de solucionarlo, use algo parecido..... gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: ok, me alegra que encuentres una solución, por favor agrega tu solución como respuesta y recuerda aceptarla como respuesta correcta, de esta manera otros con problemas similares pueden llegar a darle solución. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la solucion la tome de este link: [Post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/440209/funcion-recursiva-para-borrar-hijos/440264#440264)

aqui la funcion:

```
function borrarNodo(idnodo) {
    // Buscar nodo
    let indexBorrar = this.nodos.Dato.findIndex(item => item.id_nodo === idnodo);
    if(indexBorrar >= 0) {
        // El nodo existe, hay que proceder a borrar
        
        // Primero se buscan los hijos, item.padre = id de nodo actual
        let hijos = this.nodos.Dato.filter(item => item.padre == idnodo);
        // Recorrer y ejecutar recursivamente
        hijos.forEach(hijo => this.borrarNodo(hijo.id_nodo));

        // Ya se borraron los hijos (si había), se puede borrar el nodo
        this.nodos.Dato.splice(indexBorrar, 1);
    }
}
```